# SCTP recvmsg returns EFAULT (Bad Address)

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, sctp

I'm trying to build a very simple and basic STCP one-to-many server for testing purposes, but for some reason, the socket seems to be able to receive only one message. After receiving one message, each subsequent call to `recvmsg` returns -1 with the `errno` being `EFAULT`. This makes absolutely no sense to me, so maybe you can tell me what I'm not seeing here. `EFAULT` is supposed to be returned when

> **EFAULT**
> The receive buffer pointer(s) point outside the process's address space.

which is definitely not the case.

```cpp
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    struct sockaddr_in bind_address;
    bind_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bind_address.sin_port = htons(51338);
    bind_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_SEQPACKET, IPPROTO_SCTP);
    if (sock == -1) {
        perror("Error while creating socket");
        return 1;
    }

    int rv = bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)(&bind_address), sizeof(bind_address));
    if (rv != 0 ) {
        perror("Error while binding socket");
        return 1;
    }

    rv = listen(sock, 1);
    if (rv != 0 ) {
        perror("Error while listening");
        return 1;
    }

    struct iovec iov[1];
    iov[0].iov_base = malloc(1500);
    iov[0].iov_len = 1500;

    struct sockaddr_in sin = {};
    char control[1000] = { 0 };

    struct msghdr mhdr;
    mhdr.msg_iov = iov;
    mhdr.msg_iovlen = sizeof(iov);
    mhdr.msg_name = &sin;
    mhdr.msg_namelen = sizeof(sin);
    mhdr.msg_control = &control;
    mhdr.msg_controllen = sizeof(control);

    while (true) {
        std::memset(iov[0].iov_base, 0, iov[0].iov_len);
        std::memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));

        int recv_bytes = recvmsg(sock, &mhdr, 0);

        if (recv_bytes == -1) {
            if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK) {
                continue;
            } else {
                perror("Err");
            }
            break;
        }

        std::cout << "Received message: " << std::endl;
        std::cout << (char*)iov[0].iov_base << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is most likely because the first call to `recvmsg()` overwrites some data on the stack, causing one of the pointers inside `mhdr` to be invalid. And this is probably because of this line:

```
mhdr.msg_iovlen = sizeof(iov);
```

This should not contain the size of the array `iov` in bytes, but just the number of elements in that array, so:

```
mhdr.msg_iovlen = sizeof(iov) / sizeof(*iov); // which equals 1 in this case
```

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to have solved the problem! I was under the wrong impression, that `sizeof(array)` would return the number of array elements, not the number of occupied bytes. Back to C++ school for me I guess.

Comment: You could use [`std::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) instead, if you can use C++17. It does what you expected.